# angular.js:14700 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'MainCtrl' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am kind of new to AngularJs and I am working on a tutorial. This is my code.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-init="hourOfDay = 10">
        <div data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <h1>Angular By Bhaskar  </h1>
            <p data-ng-if="hourOfDay<12">Good Morning</p>
            <p data-ng-if="hourOfDay>17">Good Evening</p>
            <p>Hour of the day is:{{hourOfDay}} </p>
        </div>
    <script>
        var module = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        module.controller = ("MainCtrl",Main);

        function Main(){
        console.log("Main function called");
        }
    </script>

    </body>

</html>`
```

I am working with Angular 1.6.6. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `module.controller = ("MainCtrl",Main);` no need of equal to sign here

Comment: @baskar did the answer help?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes the answer worked. :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan Marked.

Comment: @bhaskardas Cool thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be declared as,

```
 module.controller("MainCtrl",Main);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var module = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function Main(){
      console.log("Main function called");
};
module.controller("MainCtrl",Main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl" data-ng-init="hourOfDay = 10">
        <div >
            <h1>Angular By Bhaskar  </h1>
            <p data-ng-if="hourOfDay<12">Good Morning</p>
            <p data-ng-if="hourOfDay>17">Good Evening</p>
            <p>Hour of the day is:{{hourOfDay}} </p>
        </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just checked where I was making the mistake. It is running now. Thanks once again :)